# Low Pass Filter Not Working

Tags: audio, filter, low-pass, passive-filter

I am trying to make a low pass filter to take normal audio signals and filter out the low frequencies so I can amplify them for a subwoofer. My problem is that the amp and sub act like there is no filter there.
[image: The resistor is 30R and the 2 caps are 10uF in parallel]

The resistor is 30R and the 2 caps are 10uF in parallel. The whole setup is (relatively) weak audio source --> low pass --> small amplifier --> subwoofer. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Show a circuit diagram.

Comment: Did you do any maths at all?

Comment: I get 265Hz cutoff frequency, which is fine. And for low frequencies the impedance seen from the input should be high enough so... I don't get your point @Asmyldof

Comment: Well for me even 900hz sines will go thru to the amp and sub

Comment: Not sure if it is a good idea to use electrolytic caps in an audio low-pass. They will be subjected to AC voltages.

Comment: Are the 900 Hz sines attenuated? A simple RC filter only drops 6dB per octave. And that is only 2 octaves (a little less). So if the input sine is around 1V, the output would be around 0.25 (you can calculate the exact value.. I am just using a ballpark number). What input and output do you see?

Comment: @VladimirCravero My point being is did the OP do any maths at all, not "Did Vlad do any maths for him to answer how appropriate the parts are". I'm not saying there's anything wrong in the parts in theory, there's something wrong in the question. Also no signal source device has been given, but if I look at the wire in the picture I can guess it's an iPod or Phone. Lord knows what the hell is on its output that's not tolerant of nearly undampened capacitance loading. And also mkeith's point: What's "going through"?

Comment: I get your point. Given the range of crap one can connect to an audio jack I'd expect Apple to have it specced for anything south of the mains. Wouldn't explain the behavior though. Maybe his sub already includes a xover or something

Comment: You will need at least a 2nd order filter for a speaker crossover, better still a 4th-order Linkwitz-Riley, and you certainly need to consider the loading effect on the device. These low impedances and the high-wattage resistor are only appropriate if the source is a power amplifier, not a 'weak audio signal'. For a line level output you should be presenting at least 1k loading, maybe double that depending on the device, and you certainly don't need a 25W resistor.

Comment: The aux is connected to one side of a stereo amp.

Comment: Unclear. If you mean the source is the speaker output of a power amplifier, it isn't a 'weak audio signal', and you don't need further amplification. If it's a tape record output or a preamp output, which seems much more likely given the plug you're using and the following amplification, you need the further amplification and much higher impedance. In both cases you need more filter stages. It's up to you to clarify this.

Comment: -1 for dumping a picture of a breadboard (sideways, no less) on us instead of a schematic.  And, closing since without a schematic this question is *unclear*.

Answer (score 2):

If your Low pass Filter is something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fl1i9n.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Your Fc is calculated like this :

[image]

Make sure about your input because I can't see your input wired correctly . One head should be connected to the resistor and the other one should be connected under the capacitors . Output will take from capacitors .